# Spring Data JPA/Boot: findBy ... or

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a finder method in my repository to find an object based on one field OR another one while supplying one parameter like:

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = Person.class, idClass = Long.class)
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findAllByIdOrAnotherId(someId);
}
```

How can I do that without using SQL?

Comment: You can annotate your method as `@Query("from Person p where p.id = ?1 or p.anotherId = ?1")`.

Answer (score 10):

I added a second parameter to the method and it worked.

```
List<Transaction> findAllByIdOrParentId(Long id, Long parentId);
```

This is just a definition for the method because I pass the same parameter to the method from the service as:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository.findAllByIdOrParentId(transactionId, transactionId);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the cool things about Spring Data JPA is the fact you can define custom queries as abstract methods in your interface.

In a nutshell, you can define a new search criteria just by specifying the `@Entity` field name you want to query by. So, let's say i want to `findAll()` by `Id` and `CustomId`. Both `Id` and `CustomId` are fields on my domain class. I would do:

```
List<Person> findAllByIdOrCustomId(someId, someCustomId);
```

For more info, research the link below: 
[Spring Data JPA - DEFINE QUERY METHODS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: I already tried that but the application doesnot even start. Here is the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/TLaWLAer

Comment: I am under corporate firewall, so not able to open and look into this link atm

Comment: please look at it when you have time and get back to me. Thanks

Comment: According to your exception logs, the problem is arising from TransactionService class while creating the bean of transactionRepository. I think you should try setter injection for transactionRepository bean instead of constructor injection

Comment: this is wrong, the application crashes with an explicit exception message: No parameter available for part CustomId SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals] NEVER. In other words, you have to provide a second argument, you can not use the same argument for both Id and CustomId.

Comment: @Melardev yes, you are correct. I have modified my answer. Thanks